# Can a static field get the name of the class that its declared in?

Tags: .net, reflection

Is it possible to refer to the name of the class that a piece of code is in?

For example when adding logging statements with log4net we initialise the log like this in each class...

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(EmploymentCorrectionUpdate));
```

Where 'EmploymentCorrectionUpdate' is the name of the class containing the code.

It would be a lot easier if the class name could be retrieved generically.

Please Note: This is a static field.

Comment: Not sure, but `this.GetType()` instead of `EmploymentCorrectionUpdate` ?

Comment: It's static and it's an initializer. That's two reasons why that won't work @psycho

Comment: Woups, shame on me. I didn't think before typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.GetType()` should do the trick, if you are not in a static context.

If you are in a static context, use

```
Type t = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
```

(from [.NET: Determine the type of “this” class in its static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081612/net-determine-the-type-of-this-class-in-its-static-method))

Answer (score 2):

yeah funny enough we use it for logging too, although I don't like using reflection for these purposes:

```
MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks TSar will this work for static fields that are not in a method too?

Comment: Actually, causes a resharper warning 'Access to a static member of a type via a derived type' Need to use MethodBase instead. I've got to give it to atticae, sorry dude.

Answer (score 1):

For an instance method it's easy (`this.GetType()`), but you need a static, class-level method.

I think that's difficult (or slow). If there was an easy/quick way, the log4net developers would have used it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for getting the class name.

MethodBase method = frame.GetMethod();
method.DeclaringType.Name