# GetType in static method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET: Determine the type of “this” class in its static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081612/net-determine-the-type-of-this-class-in-its-static-method)

How can I make `GetType()` accessible from a `static` method?

I have this abstract base class

```
abstract class MyBase
{
   public static void MyMethod()
   {
      var myActualType = GetType(); // this is an instance method
      doSomethingWith(myActualType);
   }
}
```

and an implementation of that class.  (I could have many implementations.)

```
class MyImplementation : MyBase 
{
    // stuff
}
```

How can I get `myActualType` to be `typeof(MyImplementation)`?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a simple matter. A question though, why would you want this? The point with static methods is that they don't need a instance to run, right? So why would it's type matter? Maybe your problem can be solved in a different way altogether.

Comment: I'm trying to write a convenience method to register routes for an mvc application - I'm trying to restrict them by namespace. Its abstract because I want your application to own the concrete implementation.

Comment: Then just don't write it as static, but as a method instead. Then you can easily get the type by means of `GetType()`.

Comment: @Alxandr - i dont want to instantiate a new controller.

Comment: Hmm. I see your point. You are making attribute-based routing I presume? (btw, that already exists, though I don't remember where, SO uses it amongst others). However, have you considered trying to solve the problem a bit differently? What I did was to go trough all decedents of IController in the entire assembly and use reflection on the classes to find the routes, it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the pattern i used.

```
abstract class MyBase
{
   public static void MyMethod(Type type)
   {
      doSomethingWith(type);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 59):

The "type" within a static method is always the specific type, since there is no such thing as a virtual static method.

In your case, this means you can just write:

```
 var myActualType = typeof(MyBase);
```

Since the "type" of `MyMethod`, being a static, is *always* a static method of `MyBase`.

Comment: Hi Reed - I think that the issue with your solution above is that `myActualType` would be set to the `MyBase` type, regardless of the subclass type.  If I understand the original question correctly, I think the poster is trying to get the `MyMethod` method to use the type of the current class.

Comment: @mjd79: Yes - but that's my point - a static method is always going to be typed in the base type, since a static method is part of the type, not the class using the method...

Comment: For those like me who want an equivalent of Java `MyType.class`, this is the answer for you.

Answer (score 25):

What about this?

```
abstract class MyBase<T>
{
   public static void MyMethod()
   {
      var myActualType = typeof(T);
      doSomethingWith(myActualType);
   }
}


class MyImplementation : MyBase<MyImplementation>
{
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: What stops you from doing `class Bar : MyBase<Foo>`?

Comment: Ah, that's an excellent point!  I suppose convention is the only thing that makes this work, but you're right, if someone declares the class that way, the `MyMethod` method won't work as expected.

Comment: We could do `where T : <base class name>` according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx