# Call non-static GetType() in static method?

Tags: c#, .net, types, typeof, gettype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET: Determine the type of “this” class in its static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081612/net-determine-the-type-of-this-class-in-its-static-method)

Hello is there any way to call non-static `GetType()` in non-static class without using `typeof()`?

Here is example of my code that I'm working on.

```
private static ISession GetOrCreate(ISessionFactory factory)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current!=null)
    {
        ISession session = GetExistingWebSession();
        if (session == null)
        {
            session = OpenSessionAndAddToContext(factory);
        }
        else if (!session.IsOpen)
        {
            session = OpenSessionAndAddToContext(factory);
        }            return session;
    }
}

private ISession GetExistingWebSession()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Items[GetType().FullName] as ISession;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to look up an object by its type, without knowing its type. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `typeof`?

Comment: Why use the type name as your key in the first place?

Comment: What `Type` do you want to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call an instance method from a static method like this. It makes no sense at all.

Read more about static and instance methods on MSDN:

- [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)
- [10.2.5 Static and instance members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

What's wrong with the `typeof()`?

Answer (score 2):

`typeof()` is a compile-time method. You call it against a particular type.

`GetType()` is a run-time method. You call it against a particular instance. If class (type) is static, you can't get its instance, thus call the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "this" in a static method, whether the class is static or nonstatic. Why don't you want to use typeof? It's perfectly reasonable in this case, since you always know the containing class in a static method. The only reason to use GetType() is when there's a possibility that it's called in a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call the GetType method from with `GetExistingWebSession` as it is a non static method.

However your problem is actually that you cannot call GetExistingWebSession from within `GetOrCreate`

You need some method to create an instance of your class that you can then use.

e.g.

```
MyClass c=new MyClass();
ISession session = c.GetExistingWebSession();
```