# C# keyword similar to "this" but for current class type?

Tags: c#, class, this, instance, keyword

Is there a `keyword` to refer to the current class type similar to how `this` refers to the current instance?

My intention is to avoid having to type the full class name when refering to static members or Enums but I want to prefex it with something like "this" for readability like I do for instance members. The reason being some of the class names are pretty huge and cause excessive wrapping.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can refer to static and enum types, from within the instance, without prefixing with the class name -- so I don't see the issue.  Could you perhaps post example code?

Comment: Yes I know. I just wanted the code to look consistent for Enums/statics since StyleCop enforces "this" for instances members.

Comment: damn cops ... who will police the police ???

Comment: Of course, there is namespace aliasing, which doesn't really help here.  I don't think there's anything similar for class names.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Candide since you asked, sure... it's standard for the API I'm working with to have both a `Clone()` method and a copy constructor that takes an instance of the current class. For the same of not repeating myself, and also to make it less error prone if I copy/paste, it would be neat to have keword `thistype` so I could do `public MyClass(thistype toCopy)` instead of `public MyClass(MyClass toCopy)`, or heck, even `public thisclass(thisclass toCopy)` or (CIL Style) `public .ctor(thisclass toCopy)`

Comment: @Candide also if you don't mind me asking, I'd like to ask you the same question... what are you trying to accomplish with a comment like that? Are you taking a survey or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET: Determine the type of “this” class in its static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081612/net-determine-the-type-of-this-class-in-its-static-method)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there's a keyword, but maybe as good:

```
this.GetType();
```

[`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object_methods.aspx) is one of the few methods implemented by `System.Object`.

Comment: Of course, this will get the actual runtime class of the object, which may be a subclass of the class where the code is in. This may or may not be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I updated my question with more details and unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you include the namespace with `using`, you won't indeed to enter the full path.

You can alias the class names with `using`, for instance:

```
using ClassA = Really.Deep.Class.In.Namepsace.For.SomePurpose.ClassA;
```

Comment: The problem is the class name itself is huge.

Comment: @Kurian Well, you can alias whatever you want. You know: `using X = INeedToMakeFunOfTheDeveloperThatNamedThisLongClass`.

Comment: This is incredibly useful. Think snippets that reference the current type or class in various places. Instead of replacing every occurence, a single 'using' does the trick.

Answer (score -2):

`typeof(this)` will do what you're after.

Edit:
I stand corrected.  `typeof(this)` isn't valid C#.  dbaseman is correct:  `this.GetType()` will work.

Comment: `typeof(this)` how is it supposed to work? See [typeof (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx)

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov You're right, this won't work.  I should have tried it in LINQPad first.

Comment: Can you edit more information into this answer? There's really not much point to this answer anymore.