# C# type of enclosing class

Tags: c#

Is there some way to specify the type of the enclosing class declaration statically?  If i had an instance, I could clearly use typeof(this), but statically I don't see a way.

Something like (where this_type is a placeholder):

```
public class Message
{
   public static readonly int SizeInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(this_type));
}
```

Clearly, I could just use the actual type name, but I've got several classes that follow this pattern and would like something less copy/paste error prone.

Comment: [Here's a previous question asking the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13677237/382780). Refactoring tools have made me want it less over the years, but it would still be neat.

Comment: If you had an instance, the expression `typeof(this)` would be invalid, since `typeof()` requires a type. The expression you would want is `this.GetType()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET: Determine the type of “this” class in its static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081612/net-determine-the-type-of-this-class-in-its-static-method)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType` but `typeof(Message)` is probably the cleaner way

```
public class  Message
{
   public static readonly int SizeInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
}
```

Btw, you'll get a runtime exception when you execute this code as it is trying to get the size of a managed object.

Comment: I do agree with that answer and that should be accepted as correct. The question was about getting the caller's size, not the method class owner's size... my fault :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
public class Message
{
   public static readonly int SizeInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Message));
}
```

This way, '`Message`' can also be static.

Answer (score 1):

typeof(Message) would be the closest you'd get here, but I think you'd need to use a struct rather than a class to do this from what I recall.

Answer (score 0):

What about an extension method on the type and get it dynamically instead of pushing it to a readonly static variable?

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static int SizeOfType(this System.Type tp) {
      return Marshal.SizeOf(tp);
   }

  public static int SizeOfObjectType(this object obj) {
      return obj.GetType().SizeOfType();
   }

}

// calling it from a method, 2 ways
var size1 = this.GetType().SizeOfType();
var size2 = this.SizeOfObjectType();
var size3 = typeof(string).SizeOfType();
var size4 = "what is my type size".SizeOfObjectType();
```

Answer (score 0):

After a short google search, I've seen other people using reflection to accomplish what you are talking about, but that comes with the caveat that it is probably a lot more expensive than just typing out typeof(this_type).  I'd sooner recommend just typing it out.

```
Type t = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
```

[.NET: Determine the type of “this” class in its static method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081633/2988943)