# Get Caller derived-class when calling a base-class static method

Tags: c#, reflection, derived-class

I was wondering if it's possible (even via reflection et similia) to get the caller derived-class inside of a called base-class static method.

For example, I've a base-class with a static method defined:

```
public MyBaseClass {
    public static void MyBaseClassStaticMethod() { /** ... **/ }
}
```

and a derived-from-it class:

```
public MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass { }
```

then I call:

```
MyDerivedClass.MyBaseClassStaticMethod()
```

Is it possibile, inside of method `MyBaseClassStaticMethod`, to know which is the *caller derived type*?
(i.e. `MyDerivedClass`)

I just need a string...

Comment: This is completely impossible.

Comment: @SLaks well, "completely" impossible is not quite true - you could crawl the stack-frames, for example. But there is no *good* approach to it

Comment: @MarcGravell: How would that work? The stack trace contains no hint of `MyDerivedClass`.

Comment: @MarcGravell: That wouldn't even help, unless you have the full source & Roslyn.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth ah, my bad - didn't see that it was static - I was thinking fetch the method-info's declaring type, etc

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yeah, `static` is the crucial point here.

Comment: Completely impossible is something a bit excessive. Via reflection, you can inspect the full IL of the caller method. Using libraries like http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil you can read every single line of source code and get all the information you need! I was looking for something more accessible.

Comment: As shown, it's compiled to `MyBaseClass.MyBaseClassStaticMethod()`. Inspecting the IL will only reveal this. Thus, it is impossible.

Comment: @MarcGravell Also tried crawling of stacktrace but, as Slaks said, it does not contain any reference to `MyDerivedClass`, since the called method is static.

Comment: @Teejay: The compiler replaces `MyDerivedClass` with `MyBaseClass` upon compilation. The information simply *isn't there*.

Comment: @TimS. With reflection + Cecil you can also inspect the method containing this line of code: `MyDerivedClass.MyBaseClassStaticMethod()`

Comment: @Teejay: Have you actually tried that? Just open up the assembly in your favorite decompiler - you will see that this information isn't there.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Oh! Just realized that decompiling with .net Reflector! Please write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it since that's the real point here!

Comment: @Teejay: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16301970/572644) already contains this information.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Just seen the update! Accepted and up-voted!

Comment: @Teejay: Looks like you undid the accept. Is there something new you found out? If so, be sure to post it.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No, it's just my internet connection....

Comment: Never say never. There is a workaround for this, see answer by @Loki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible - by no means. `static` methods are not polymorphal and as such this information simply doesn't exist.
Consider redesigning your code.

Update:

Upon compilation, the compiler replaces `MyDerivedClass` with the class the static method is actually declared on, in your case `MyBaseClass`.
So even in the IL you don't see `MyDerivedClass`. The information exists *only* in your source code. It doesn't exist in your compiled assembly.

Comment: Thank you. Actually this is only an attempt to do a runtime-check for programmers' errors, when using this library. I can do without.

Comment: This is the correct answer and well explained. The other answers try to work around this limitation by changing the requirements of the OP.

Answer (score 9):

Generics in following way can be used to solve your scenario

```
public class BaseClass<TDerived> where TDerived : BaseClass<TDerived>
{
    public static void LogCallerType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(TDerived).Name);
    }
}

public class FooClass : BaseClass<FooClass> { }

public class BooClass : BaseClass<BooClass> { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FooClass.LogCallerType();
        BooClass.LogCallerType();
    }
}
```

This will in turn output the following

```
1. FooClass
2. BooClass
```

Comment: This is going to scratch an itch I've been having for quite a while trying to get C# calling context in the same way you can access it in Javascript.

Comment: This is a bad workaround. Just because something works, doesn't mean it's safe/correct. What happens if you declare (for example, by accident) something like: FooClass : BaseClass<BooClass>

Comment: Is there another workaround that's not so bad? Really curious.

Comment: this is actually pretty good

Comment: @MladenB.what happens if you type (for example, by accident) an SQL DELETE statement instead of an UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 0):

A static method is statically bound to a certain class and does not really participate in the inheritance-chain. Thus it does not exist in the derived class. The static method therefor does not know that it was actually used in the derived class.

You can however - through a compiler-trick - access the static member from your derived class. As of [this post on MSDN-forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59a77468-0b5a-4342-9bc8-c6dadff03130/inheritance-and-static-members?forum=clr) a static member-access from a derived class is translated to a call from the base-class containing the static member. So `MyDerivedClass.MyBaseClassStaticMethod` is translated to `MyBaseClass.MyBaseClassStaticMethod`. Thus `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType` will allways return `MyBaseClass`.

So in short: **no, it´s not possible** to get the derived type from a static member.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the static method will not have access to the instance that is calling it.  A static method is different from a normal class method in that it does not have access the 'this' reference to a class instance.

If you passed 'this' as a parameter to the static method, then you can try casting it as follows.  Assume you have a number of derived class which you want to test for.

```
public static void MyBaseClassStaticMethod(MyBaseClass callingInstance)
{
    MyDerivedClass myDerivedClass = callingInstance as MyDerivedClass;
    MyDerivedClass2 myDerivedClass2 = callingInstance as MyDerivedClass2;
    MyDerivedClass3 myDerivedClass3 = callingInstance as MyDefivedClass3;
    ...

    // test for which derived class is calling
    if (myDerivedClass != null)
        ...
    else if (myDerivedClass2 != null)
        ...

    ...
}
```

Comment: The question is not about `this` instance.